# How can I modify the code for the turtlesim package?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let us say that i ran a turtlesim_node `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` and then ran another node with a different name `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node __name:=my_turtle`. Now i ran the teleop node : `rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key` .
Now when i move the teleop key, i am publishing messages to bothe the turtlesim nodes. I do not want this but i guess by default it is so that the teleop node will publish the messages to all the turtlesim_nodes present.

1. How can i have multiple `turtlesim_node` running but publish only to 1.
2. Using rosservice, how can i clear the content of both the turtlesim nodes at the same time ? using `rosservice call /clear` clears the default node.
3. Is it possible to modify its code or there is some understanding problem from my side ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288747/how-can-i-modify-the-code-for-the-turtlesim-package-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now when i move the teleop key, i am publishing messages to bothe the turtlesim nodes. I do not want this but i guess by default it is so that the teleop node will publish the messages to all the turtlesim_nodes present.

No, that is not how this works. The teleop node *publishes* to the `turtle1/command_velocity` topic ([here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers_tutorials/blob/bfe4aa5d5f1417d4bf1fca9fe99f50b3405a7f22/turtle_teleop/scripts/turtle_teleop_joy.py#L59)), to which all instances of `turtlesim_node` *subscribe*. That is why they all receive the same message.

> 1 . How can i have multiple `turtlesim_node` running but publish only to 1.

Technically, you can't, as publications are not "to" a certain node, but to a topic. Any node can subscribe to that topic, and publications are *anonymous*. You have no way to specify a recipient.

What you could do however, is use [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) to effectively 'rewire' a node to publish or subscribe to a different topic. You could use this to make one `turtlesim_node` subscribe to `turtle1/command_velocity` (the default) and the other to `turtle2/command_velocity`. Now if `turtle_teleop` publishes to `turtle1/command_velocity`, only the first `turtlesim_node` will receive the messages.

This effectively achieves what you are asking, but do please note the difference: you're still not sending messages "to" a specific `turtlesim_node`, you're just making sure that only one of them "tunes in" on the data stream sent out by `turtle_teleop`.

> 2 . Using rosservice, how can i clear the content of both the turtlesim nodes at the same time ? using `rosservice call /clear` clears the default node.

You can't.

In contrast to messages, service invocations *are* directed to one particular recipient, namely the service provider (or server). In this case most likely the last `turtlesim_node` that came up 'claims' the name `clear` and responds to calls to the service.

Remapping can help you here as well, but only to make sure the `clear` services are reachable for both (or all) instances.

> 3 . Is it possible to modify its code or there is some understanding problem from my side ?

From the above, it would seem there is no 'need' to modify the code, as remapping seems to solve issue 1, and issue 2 is not possible, even if you'd modify the source.

If you'd still like to take a look, see [ros/ros_tutorials/turtlesim](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/821a8ae33c6da1a70e21453392f6980380f670f8/turtlesim). Clone it into a Catkin workspace, build it and be sure to `source` the `devel/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
#q203129 might be interesting as some background on how coupled nodes are when they use the different communication patterns supported by ROS.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-16**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for such a quick and effective response. I tried this and this works. Just one thing : How can i remap the topics of the node `my_turtle`. By default it always changes that of the `turtlesim_node`.

```
rosrun turtlesim my_turtle /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/turtle2/cmd_vel
```

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-16**:
this says couldnt find an executable named my_turtle. When I use the default i.e. `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/turtle2/cmd_vel` it works for the turtlesim_node

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
I would recommend you start using launch files. `rosrun` can be used -- also with remapping -- but launch files will make this much easier.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
Also: try to avoid speccing absolute topic names (ie: remove the leading `/`).